# How to compile SASS/SCSS files on the server?

Tags: css, amazon-web-services, sass, content-management-system

I have an applications on AWS styled using SASS(SCSS). The SCSS files are structured on a modular way and I have one file with all the variables making it very easy to rebrand.

I've built an CMS and I would like to let the user to pick his colors and fonts and once done, by clicking on a button I would like to do the following:

1) Write to the variables file the values entered on the CMS.
2) Compile the SCSS files, generate a new CSS file on the server and replace the current one if no errors.

Any ideas?

Comment: Generally this is done by persisting styling attributes to a database and using javascript to inject inline styling for the styling that the user has control over.  I have never seen the pattern you are looking for in any production system.

Comment: That's a valid approach and it would work, but I would header update the CSS sheet.

Comment: did you found solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that is a bad idea to begin with. You could just take the direct CSS input from the user instead of SASS. Why? Because the job of pre-compiling the stylesheet is left to the user who is uploading it, not the person who is hosting it. You could give them a space to write the CSS, but if they want a pre-processor, then I guess you'd have to install / run RUBY.

Comment: On this system, the user wouldn't have any CSS knowledge and the file would not be uploaded as it would be compiled on the same place as it's hosted. I was thinking on build an API to take the user input, write to a file, compile the CSS  file (with RUBY) from the SASS files on the server and save it. We are building it anyway, but I was looking for someone who have experienced the same path on the past to avoid the same mistakes.

Comment: Ok, but my point is, why do you have to use a preprocessor? It's like going around the head to touch your nose?

Comment: I have over 30 different partial SCSS files on my structure reading from the variables on one file. I understanding your perspective and you have a point, but considering our modular architecture it would require a lot of refactoring. We have a server in house and we have AWS. I can host APIs on both and I can install ruby and sass on either. The solution that I'm working on is as described on the question. I would like to write on the variable files and compile it all together.

Comment: @ViniciusSantana Did you ever find a solution for this that you were happy with? I'm looking into the same thing.

Comment: I ask out of interest, and coming from a larger developer team where many devs are interacting on the same codebase.
Why compile on a local machine, does this not cause issues with devs running there on compile service different versions causing different CSS, and the like, wouldn't it be better to be on a server and all devs are inputting into common SCSS files and the compile is run with a watch on the server and the result is put directly into the branch.
??? What is best approach?
Are there answers to this question that include Docker or Linux instances?